# counting characters inside double quotes with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

only  as library, no loops allowed (for, do, while all not allowed)
recursion must be used

a function:int count_chars_in_matched_dquote(const char line[], int start)
parameters cannot be changed, array line is the input, start is always 0 when function is first called

I've only managed to count the number of characters within the first pair of quotes, and cannot count the second part, i.e.: "hi" outputs 2, but "hi""HI" outputs 2 which is incorrect (correct ans 4)

Comment: "only as library, no loops allowed" is this your homework?

Comment: Are you allowed to write your own functions, or do you have to use only the given function `int count_chars_in_matched_dquote(const char line[], int start)`?

Comment: yeah is my homework and idk how to do it...
you can write helper functions but no loops are allowed, only recursions

Comment: I would go for two functions, say `f1` and `f2`. `f1` would read chars until it encounters the opening `"`, then call `f2`, which would read and count characters recursivley until it encounters the closing `"´ after which it would call `f1` again. That's just a basic concept, but I hope you get the idea.